# In GAP, for special group $M$ of order 512 how we find one answer of equality Inn(X)\cong M,?

Tags: group-theory, gap

Let $M$ be the under group,

```
F:=FreeGroup("a","b");;
R:=ParseRelators(F,"a^8=b^8=[a,b]^8=1, [[a,b],b]=[[a,b],a]=1");;
M:=F/R;;
```

Now we want to find a group $X$ such that $Inn(X)\cong M$. 
I wrote the under program:

```
n:=9;;
i:=0;;
T:=SmallGroup(2^n, i+1);;
C:=Center(T);;
G:=T/C;;
while 
    IsomorphismGroups(G, M)=fail do
    i:=(i+1) mod NumberSmallGroups(2^n);
    n:=n+Maximum(1-i, 0);
    T:=SmallGroup(2^n, i+1);
    C:=Center(T);
    G:=T/C;
od;
```

But my computer can not load it. Do there exists a easy or better program for this question?

thank you

Comment: I've edited the question to show how to properly include the code. It must be indented by 4 spaces. However, I still can't digest the question. Please explain the logic of your code and what you're trying to achieve, and also include the error message that GAP displays when you're trying to execute your code.

Comment: P.S. Irrespectively of what you're trying to achieve, I suggest to take a structural approach and follow the Software Carpentry lesson on GAP. [This part](http://alex-konovalov.github.io/gap-lesson/05-small-groups.html) covers exactly the search in the small groups library.

Comment: Yes. It is better that we start $n$ of number10. I want to find $T$ such that $T/Z(T) $ is isomorphic to $M$. I think that the codes are correct, only the comuter can not load it. Computer can load and find $T$   for groups $M=SmallGroup(8, 3)$ and $M=SmallGroup(64, 18)$.

Comment: I encourage you to not to be satisfied with the explanation "I think that the codes are correct, only the copmuter can not load it." You need to learn how to debug the code, and understand what's happening after you load it. Is there an error? If not, what it is doing? Is it checking groups or hangs somewhere? Can you add `Print` statements to see the progress of this computation, etc.

Comment: The `SmallGroup` library does not cover 2-groups of order greater than $2^9$.  There are simply far too many of them (around 50 billion of order $2^{10}$, which is over 99% of all groups of order at most 2000).  So your code will immediately hit this problem after the first loop, and it should spit out a fairly obvious error message to this effect.  The way you define $n$ in the loop is also highly mysterious in and of itself.

Comment: If you could improve the question by giving some more details, I could try to post another answer with the code review - even though the particular answer is given thanks to @ahulpke and some luck, it could be good for the future to learn some GAP programming tricks and common pitfalls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would look at a Schur Cover as being a good candidate (there is no guarantee that it will satisfy your condition, but you can hope to be lucky):

```
gap> hom:=EpimorphismSchurCover(M);
[ f1, f2 ] -> [ a, b ]
gap> C:=Source(hom);
<fp group on the generators [ f1, f2 ]>
```

Note that the source group (in the current version) always is an Fp group, this somehow limits the applicability if the group is larger.

```
gap> Size(C);
16384
gap> Index(C,Centre(C));
512
gap> IsomorphismGroups(C/Centre(C),M);
[ (1,483,79,227,361,212,70,489)(2   [...]
```

So we were lucky and found a group $X$ as you wanted.

Comment: Thanks - I've added the missing line to the example.

Comment: The "limited applicability" is probably because FP groups are horribly inefficient for actual computations.  Usually one wants a permutation group representation.  One can use `IsomorphismPermGroup` to get a faithful representation to a permutation group.  Applying `Image` to the result gives the isomorphic permutation group.  The degree is not guaranteed to be anywhere close to minimal, though, and smaller degrees are more efficient.  You can use `SmallerDegreePermutationRepresentation` to get a faithful rep of a perm group to a (usually) smaller degree one; use `Image` as before.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy  Yes, one can convert to a permutation group, but even that may fail in practice if the fp group is too large.